# Spring Boot returns 415: Unsupported Media Type on create

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot. I'm trying to create a `create` endpoint which only expects an object with only a `title` and `body`. The `Uuid` and `created_at` should be generated. I try to send a `POST` request with Postman adding the values under `Body` and `form-data`. But it returns the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-12-09T15:11:02.659+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/tasks"
}
```

Controller method:

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody TaskDTO requestTask) {
        System.out.println(requestTask);
        Task newTask = new Task(requestTask.uuid.toString(), requestTask.title, requestTask.body, requestTask.created_at);
        Task task = taskRepository.save(newTask);


        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .body(task);
    }
```

Task.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID uuid;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String title;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String body;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @GeneratedValue
    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    public Task(UUID uuid, String title, String body, LocalDateTime created_at) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public Task() {

    }
}
```

TaskDTO.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TaskDTO {
    public UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    public String title;
    public String body;
    public LocalDateTime created_at = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the REST API you are trying to implement, the request you are submitting using Postman is not form-data. The header `Content-Type` should be `application/json`. And  the `body` should be like:

```
{
    "title" : "The Godfather",
    "body" : "I am going to make him an offer he can't refuse."
}
```

Screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- From postman select body -> select raw -> select json

screenshot
[image]